# android -universal-image-loader-1.8.4 - cache on disk

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal-image-loader-1.8.4-with-sources jar file ,I've added this file into my lib directory .
I've a few question .

I've some static images in my app that they never change and I want to save them on sd card. this is the code I'm using :

```
optionsimg= new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.empty)
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.empty)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty).cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc(true).build();
    imageListener = new ImageDisplayListener();
```

the problem is this : cacheOnDisc(true)
if I put true in cacheOnDisc , it gives me this error :The method cacheOnDisc() in the type DisplayImageOptions.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (boolean) 
if I put nothing in it , there wouldn't be any error .

what is the problem and How can I save all my images for ever on sd card using this jar file ?

thanks you

Comment: you should put size of catch that you want in it

Comment: @mhp thanks for the reply , i've lots of image , if I want to save lots of them , how much should I put in?

Comment: it does not accept any number you can see max number in ImageLoader site or gitHub page and use that

Answer (score -1):

the problem is not : cacheOnDisc(true) if I put true in cacheOnDisc

**Here problem is image loader version..i faced the same problem.just use updated universal image loader. i worked me...**

**Solution:**

**use this version : use [ universal-image-loader-1.9.4 or above ]**

-Thanks